# android studio kotlin error Caused by: org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.CompilationErrorException: Compilation error. See log for more details

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-activity, build

Caused by: org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.CompilationErrorException: Compilation error. See log for more details

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/blue_background"
tools:context=".FeedActivity">
```

[image]

Comment: Click the "Build promodro" line in the output window. It'll give you more information, including *what* didn't compile.

Comment: if it's about the `FeedActivity`, maybe you need to specify the fully qualified name?

Comment: @Asli you are using dataBinding? or viewBinding? in your activity?

Comment: you can click on :app:compileDebugKotlin and see what is the the problem itself. Output is a general problem

Answer (score 0):

Remove the tool context or provide the full path of the FeedActivity after that clean the project rebuild the project

Comment: i didn't understand " full path of the FeedActivity"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I was missing the "}" tag in another file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).